# What properties does dollar cost averaging have?

Tags: probability

For example, say I have a bet with positive expected value. Say my  money can become 2.1 times or lost with probability of 50%. There is a technique that specify how much money I can bet to say maximize geometric mean.

Does dollar cost averaging maximize such criteria? If not how should we modify dollar cost averaging so we can maximize expected value of geometric fund grows on an investment with a certain alpha? For example.

Answer (score 0):

Dollar cost averaging is not appropriate in this type of scenario (one-time bets rather than continuous investment). What you need is the Kelly criterion. In your example, it suggests betting 1/22 of your total wealth in each period. So if you started with $\$$440, you should bet $\$$20. Let's say you win, gaining $\$$22 for a total of $\$$462. Of this amount you should bet $\$$21 in the next period. So the amount invested depends on your current worth, unlike dollar-cost averaging.